# Why do I get "Thin adapter not found"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, thin

I'm an iOS developer with very little Ruby experience, trying to follow "[Getting Started with iOS Mobile Development and a Sinatra API](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-ios-development-sinatra-cedar)" on getting an API running on Heroku.

I grabbed the [sample project](https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-ios-api) on Git, so I know I have an identical setup to what I'm supposed to have.

I've bundle installed, and thought that everything should be ready to go, but whenever I do a `foreman start` I get this:

```
2:14:56 web.1     | started with pid 5140
12:14:57 web.1     | No adapter found for {MY PROJECT'S FILEPATH}
12:14:57 web.1     | process terminated
12:14:57 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

What am I doing wrong, or what do I need to do to get this to run?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing a *config.ru* file that is required to know how to start the application.

Create a file in your root called *config.ru* and add the following to it:

```
require './api'
run Sinatra::Application
```

You can test this is correct by running `rackup` in the project root.  If the config file is correct then your server should start.

Please read [When to use config.ru](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#When%20to%20use%20a%20config.ru?) and http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack for further information.

Comment: I had to capitalize the A in Sinatra::Application, but then it worked.  Thanks, and thanks for the links!

Comment: This is a good answer, but the original post from Heroku that is linked to (that I was also just checking out) recommends skipping the config.ru file: "you’ll get more control over how your app is executed if you skip config.ru and instead declare your own web process type in a Procfile."  However, following their instructions causes this problem, that you have, fortunately, solved for us.